# Can't toggle. Bootstrap 5 js not initialized properly?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpacker, bootstrap-5

I have an issue with my Bootstrap 5.0.0-beta2 implementation. I can expand my navbars and accordions, but not collapse them.

It seems to be a problem with the initialization of the js.

Because if I load a page that doesn't have the elements, and then browse to a page that has (my pages do not reload because I am using [hotwire/Turbo](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails)) I can both expand and collapse them. Though these errors are printed to the console when toggling:

```
Uncaught TypeError: No method named "toggle"
    at Function.collapseInterface (bootstrap.bundle.js:1942)
    at bootstrap.bundle.js:2001
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.bundle.js:1985)
    at HTMLDocument.handler (bootstrap.bundle.js:414)
```

Any idea what I should do differently?

I am using webpack to pack my assets for my Ruby on Rails app (using the [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) gem). Here is my webpacker setup:

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "bootstrap"
import "../stylesheets/application"
window.Turbo = Turbo
window.bootstrap = require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js')
Rails.start()
```

```css
/* app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss */

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Rails: '@rails/ujs',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)
module.exports = environment
```

Additionally, I am sharing a few images to show the transitions that take place when I toggle after having reloaded the page.

My original state looks like this.

[image: Original state]

When toggling the navbar, it transitions like expected:

[image: Expanding state]

It ends up in the expanded state:

[image: Expanded state]

But when I press the navbar-toggler icon the navbar doesn't collapse. Instead, it transitions through the expanding state (second image) and ends up in the expanded state (third image).

Comment: Try to change ```window.bootstrap = require(...)``` with ```import * from 'bootstrap'``` maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried `Bootstrap 5.0.0-beta2`, `Rails 6.1` with your config code.

The problem seems to be the way you load `bootstrap` object, that is the line:

```js
// Conflict somehow
window.bootstrap = require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js')
```

You could use `const require` or `import` instead from [Doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/#npm):

> const bootstrap = require('bootstrap') or import bootstrap from 'bootstrap' will load all of Bootstrap’s plugins onto a bootstrap object.

```js
const bootstrap = require('bootstrap') // or
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
```

Or you could load `bootstrap` object globally:

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Rails: '@rails/ujs',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    bootstrap: ['bootstrap']
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Comment: Great @eux both of those lines solves the problem. Only this causes other issues. If I reference `bootstrap` in my own js files I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined`. For example I have a file that I include like this: `import "../javascripts/bootstrap_toast"` and from within that file I run `new bootstrap.Toast(my_toast_elm, {}).show();`. So how do I share the new `bootstrap` const with the wider scope?

Comment: You could load `bootstrap` object globally just like 'Popper' in `config/webpack/environment.js`, check out details on the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Can award the bounty in 10 hours :-)

Comment: Glad to help : )

Comment: The import did not work for me but the const/require declaration did.